# Should use inbuilt libraries or define classes?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

what is recommended in competitive programming defining classes or using the java libraries?eg.stack or linked lists.Does performance of code depends on it?

Comment: If library functions exist, use them. No point in re-inventing wheels unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you don't need to write your own classes for saving and managing some objects in a list.

I recommend you not to invent the wheel again.
Except you do it for a learning purpose.

The problem with writing your own classes for critical operations is that you can't do it better than a team of some pretty smart heads. Neither do I.